# Dynamically create div inside table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a div dynamically in jQuery as mentioned in the below code appending to the form.

```
 var temp = document.createElement("div");
     temp.setAttribute("id", "test");
```

Form:

```
<form id="test1" method="get">
</form>
```

I am trying to have a table created dynamically and need to have this inside a table?

To form table dynamically:

```
 var tableHeader = '<table border="1"> <thead> <tr><th>QueryName</th><th>Description</th><th>Modified Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
 $("#test").prepend(tableHeader);
```

Now I need to have `<td>` (Which I need to create) inside which I need the div element I created. Like this:

```
<table>
...
....
<tr> 
<td>
<div id="test">   // Div  i created dynamically in the top(1st line)
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

How do I achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: 1. Note that IDs are case sensitive. Test !== test. 2. IDs are unique identifiers and must be unique in the DOM. So you cannot have a form and a div with the ID of "test"

Comment: @mark Agree. Changed the ID. This is the sample code i came for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the table first?
and then append the table into the dom.
give an id to the td where you want to insert your div.

$('#td-id').html({div-content-goes-here}).

the html() function puts its contents inside the selected dom node.
you can also use append(),

Comment: Am trying to change the Existing logic. I already have a Div which formed looping through the Json response and now am trying to change with minimal effort by adding table to it

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.setAttribute("id", "test");
console.log(temp);
var tableHeader = '<table border="1"> <thead> <tr><th>QueryName</th><th>Description</th><th>Modified Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
$('body').append(tableHeader);
$('table').append(temp);
```

Also check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/fxmy2/) and share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

To append the div to the td of the table, you must first have such a td. The code below checks its existence and adds it if it doesn't exist.

```
<form id="test1" method="get"></form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tableHeader = '<table border="1"> <thead> <tr><th>QueryName</th><th>Description</th><th>Modified Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
$("#test1").prepend(tableHeader);

if ($('#test1 table tr td:first-child').size()==0) {
    console.log('Table has no TDs. Creating a row.');
    $('#test1 table tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
}

var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.setAttribute("id", "test");
    temp.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test Div Inserted'));

// appends the DIV to the first TD of the TABLE under #test1 FORM
$('#test1 table tr td:first-child').append(temp);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JYzbJ/3/).

Answer (score 0):

@user2067567, here is a healthy approach, put an id on your dynamic table, before you append it to the DOM...

```
var tableHeader = '<table border="1" id="mtableid"> <thead> <tr><th>QueryName</th><th>Description</th><th>Modified Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
```

...Then make your base point for manipulating your new table from this ID...

```
var mtable = $('#mtableid');
```

...Then look for the tr row you want to enter...

```
var firstrow   = mtable.find('tr').eq(1);
```

...Then append content to the first row...

```
$('<td><div>...</div></td>').appendTo(firstrow);
```

This is all untested, but posted just to give you a general idea.
Let me know if you want further details.

Answer (score 0):

var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.setAttribute("id", "test");

```
var tableHeader = '<table border="1"> <thead> <tr><th>QueryName</th><th>Description</th><th>Modified Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
$("#test1").prepend(tableHeader);

$('tr').append(temp);
$('div').html('create div content');
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is quite simple but there is an important point that you've missed to explain. Which tr do you want to append to. Do you want to create a new tr for every div you want to append to the table or is there some other logic?